# Threads/Sockets in a client server mini application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I basically try to make a simple domain resolver using sockets.

I am pretty far and I its working how it is now. Except my main function where I try to make a *thread* which keeps listening and waiting for another call. After I type www.google.com it gives me the address but when I try it again, it does nothing. I think the socket closes or something. I wanted to use threads and `while` loops but I'm struggling with this problem for hours.

Client side ( *EchoClient.java* )

```
package tetst222;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;



public class EchoClient 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  try
  {
   Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1350);

   PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);

   InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
   BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

   String line;
   while((line = bin.readLine()) != null)
   {
    System.out.println(line);
   }

   //sock.close();
  }

  catch(IOException ioe)
  {
   System.err.println(ioe);
  }
 }
}
```

And this code:

Server side ( *EchoServer.java* )

```
package tetst222;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EchoServer //implements Runnable
{


 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {


  try
  {
   ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(1350);

    while(true)
    {
 // open socket
 Socket client = sock.accept();

 PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);

 printout.println("Je bent succesvol verbonden met de host");

 printout.println("Geef een hostnaam op waarvan je het IP-adres wilt achterhalen:");

 //get input from client
 InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader bufin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

 /*
 Thread t = new Thread();
 t.start();
  */

 String host = "";
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Typ de host die u wilt resolven: ");
 host = sc.nextLine();

 try
 {
       InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(host);
       System.out.println(ia);
 }
 catch(UnknownHostException uhe)
 {            
       System.out.println(uhe.toString());
 }catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
 }  

 client.close();

}

  }catch(IOException ioe)
  {
   System.err.println(ioe);
  }
 }

/*
public void run() {

 String host = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Typ de host die u wilt resolven: ");
host = sc.nextLine();

try
{
      InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(host);
      System.out.println(ia);
}
catch(UnknownHostException uhe)
{            
      System.out.println(uhe.toString());
}catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
}  

 } 
 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server don't handle client requests. It wait for new client (socket.accept) and read default system input (System.in) not a socket, and after just close client connection.

it look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Typ de host die u wilt resolven: ");

        String host = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            System.out.println(ia);
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println(uhe.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

At the client side you should read address from console, write it to socket (send request), then read data from socket (take response) and out to console;

At the server side you must accept client connection (socket.accept), read data from socket (take request), handle it (InetAddress.getByName(host)) and send response back to the client socket.